# Use net Write to send data\r\n is sent as a string instead of eof

Tags: string, go

I want use socket send 'info\r\n' to redis server by net, send data is 69 6e 66 6f 5c 72 5c 6e
but i want send data is 69 6e 66 6f 0d 0a,\r\n treated as an string and wrong becomes 5c 72 5c 6e

send data is string in code i turn string to []byte and conn.write

This sending seems to be wrong, what is the correct sending method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data `69 6e 66 6f 5c 72 5c 6e` is:

```
b := []byte{0x69, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x5c, 0x72, 0x5c, 0x6e}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(b))
```

Which outputs:

```
"info\\r\\n"
```

It contains a backslash, an `r`, another backslash and an `n` character at the end.

You want to send a carriage return `\r` and a newline character `\n`, you don't have to send these "literally". `\r` and `\n` are single byte data, not 2-character sequences.

Your data should be:

```
b = []byte{0x69, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x6f, '\r', '\n'}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(b))
```

Which outputs:

```
"info\r\n"
```

Or simply:

```
b = []byte("info\r\n")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(b))
```

Which outputs the same. Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Tukea0pQvEt).

Know that the string literal `"info\r\n"` is an interpreted string literal, `\r` and `\n` sequences in it will be interpreted as single characters (the carriage return and newline characters). This is detailed in [Spec: String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: thanks, i found  the right way, this is work

`s := fmt.Sprintf("%x","info\r\n")
decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(s)`